# Use viewed item's ID and place it into button's destination URL

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I'm a wanna be programmer with my first question here :)

I'm using SP 2010 Foundation without any option to program on server side or with SharePoint Designer. I need to add a button on a "View form" of a list 
(`https://SITE/LIST/DispForm.aspx?ID=384`)

The button's code is:

```
<input class="afxAddItemButton" onclick="window.location.href=&#39;https://SITE/PAGE_ADDRESS.aspx?dbSpListId=ITEM ID HERE&#39;" type="button" value="Button name"/>
```

I also have a JS script registered on this page. This code is used on another page to read dbSpListId value from URL, so I guess it could be modified to read ID value from "View item" page:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to place the value extracted by JS into the button code. Is it even possible?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the code below:

```
document.querySelector('.afxAddItemButton').onclick = function redirect() {
    window.location = "https://SITE/PAGE_ADDRESS.aspx?dbSpListId=" + GetUrlKeyValue("ID")
}
```

If you place this code before you button you might want to wrap the code in

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I will need further guidance. On the "Display Form" page I have a Content Editor Web Part, with button code mentioned before, and below is the standard view properties form. Where and in which type of Web Part should I place the code you provided? And do I need to modify the button code? I have tried multiple options, still it's not working.

Comment: It should should suffice to wrap the code in script tags and place it after the button in your CEWP. No changes to the button required.